# JS Event Listener on Dynamic Buttons

Tags: javascript

Wondering why when adding more than 1 dynamic button their toggle bg color listener won't work consistently.

If I add let's say 3 buttons, listener for button 1 & 3 will work while button 2 won't.

```js
//document.ready
function ready(fn) {
  if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading") {
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

//event listener on dynamic buttons not in DOM
ready(function() {
  document.querySelector('.makeB').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("toggle bg");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    btn.classList.add('elis');

    var newBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.elis');
    newBtns.forEach(function(i) {
      i.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.body.classList.toggle('bg');
      })
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.bg {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="makeB">create button</button>
```

Researched a bit of bubbling & event delegation options to see if that would help (similar to jquery approach `$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );` but no luck)

**How to make dynamic buttons work consistently and what's the issue with the current scenario?**

*JS only please (no jQuery).*

Comment: Nothing to stop you from adding the eventListener to a parent wrapper and then test the event target

Comment: @mplungjan Well, that code doesn't work here in snippet.

Comment: I see the effect on Chrome (Windows 64 bit v66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to simplify your code would be to use event delegation. Just add `click` event listener to body or some other enclosing container (possibly the closest one) and execute its code only when `event.target` is one of your buttons.

That way you will skip that part where you are adding event listeners to the same buttons over and over again.

```js
function ready(fn) {
  if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading") {
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.className === 'elis') {
    document.body.classList.toggle('bg');
  }
});

ready(function() {
  document.querySelector('.makeB').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.textContent = "toggle bg";
    btn.classList.add('elis')
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  })
})
```

```css
.bg {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="makeB">create button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Matus, this approach is appreciated as it would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```js
//document.ready
function ready(fn) {
  if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading") {
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

//event listener on dynamic buttons not in DOM
ready(function() {
  document.querySelector('.makeB').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("toggle bg");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    btn.classList.add('elis');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.body.classList.toggle('bg');
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.bg {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="makeB">create button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like `querySelectorAll` listeners were conflicting, was simpler than I thought.

Comment: Yes, you were adding more than one listener to the same button

Comment: Even though this is a solution to your problem, another issue is being generated. Right now every button will have it's own event listener added. If you add 50 buttons, you will have 50 event listeners. The proper solution would be to use [Event Delegation](https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/part-4-what-is-event-delegation-in-javascript-f5c8c0de2983). Basically you add an `event listener` on the parent (which is in this case, the `body`. a better practice would be to add a parent around the generated buttons) and check if the clicked element has the properties of your generated element.

Comment: Yes thanks for the observation Stefan, just noticed that as well.

Answer (score 1):

They do work.  The problem is you're just adding more listeners every time you add a button, so they only look like they work when there are an odd number of listeners on any particular button.  Just add a listener to the button before you put it in the document.

Comment: Thanks, consider also sharing fiddle for future reference, but +10 for your time.